# How do I connect these three seemingly irrelevant clauses of lyrics?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

I am studying the lyrics of [美しければそれでいい by 石川智晶](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=B24447). I am quite confused by the first three lines in this part:

> 未来と指切りするのをやめた**のは**
>
> 痛みから遠く逃れよう**としても**
>
> 冷えた風がほら髪を揺らすよ
>
> 何処で答えを探せばいい

From my understanding:

The first line says "I stopped making pinky promises with the future のは". The second line says "Even if I try to run away from the pain..." The third line says "Look, the cold wind is stroking your hair".

I feel like I've misunderstood something, because:

- usually the clause after のは says something about the clause before it, but here the two clauses seem unrelated. Is the のは just filler, and that the two lines are totally separate?
- The second and third lines has this "〜としても、〜" structure, but I can't seem to fit the meaning into it either. Maybe the "cold wind" is the "pain" that "I" am trying to run away from? That's kind of a stretch though...

Comment: "i stopped making promises with the future because even when I try to run far away from the pain, a cold wind just blows through my hair" is my interpretation. Like, even when they run away they are still reminded of the past, so how can they focus on the future? It is missing a から or something, definitely, but honestly I've seen this a bunch in songs. Japanese people tell me not to think too hard on it and I've been doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you on your take about 〜のは. We all expect a cause/reason why they stopped doing that, yet that is not given. It's unsettling.

〜としても is a little more comfrotable because presumably it means one cannot escape the pain because the cold wind blows your hair. It's still somewhat nonsensical but I think it's at an acceptable level as a lyrics.